# Can I run nodejs child-process (command line) in heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, child-process, mongodump

I have created an app.js file that tries to run node span child-process. With that child process I tried to run mongodump (mongodb utility to create backups). In my local computer that codes works but in my node server in heroku the code fails and throws an error like:

```
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655225+00:00 app[web.1]: node:events:371
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655250+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655250+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655250+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655251+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: spawn mongodump ENOENT
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655252+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655252+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655252+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655253+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655253+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: -2,
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655254+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ENOENT',
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655254+00:00 app[web.1]:   syscall: 'spawn mongodump',
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655254+00:00 app[web.1]:   path: 'mongodump',
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655255+00:00 app[web.1]:   spawnargs: [
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655255+00:00 app[web.1]:     '--gzip',
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655255+00:00 app[web.1]:     '--uri',
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655255+00:00 app[web.1]:     'my_mongo_atlas_uri,
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655255+00:00 app[web.1]:     '--forceTableScan'
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655256+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]
2021-08-20T01:17:29.655256+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-08-20T01:17:29.732198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Can anyone suggest what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

So, i have figured this out by myself.
Heroku doesn't understand mongodump or mongorestore or any other mongodb utilities command by itself. You have to add mongodb utilities build-packs to you app/server. You can add them by:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/uhray/heroku-buildpack-mongo.git
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

After adding this, redeploy you server. Now it can support mongo utilities commands.
Reference taken from: heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/uhray/heroku-buildpack-mongo.git